stacked bar chart in Excel with offset
I would like to create a stacked bar chart, like in this post Display dataset in Horizontal bar with offset in the Excel?
I dont understand the details to how set the chart in a way to start every bar at the beginning of their initial date.
This is what I want to obtain
What I want
This is what I obtained
What I get
